# How to change the blog page url on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, html, cpanel, blogs

My website like www.example.com. I need to go to redirect a url as 'press.example.com' when click on the blog. I went through a lot of reference but could not find any solution. How can I change the url for only the blog page. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this is done by creating a custom menu item which links to an external link, as this is a separate site the blog settings in the example.com website are not relevant in this case.

Comment: Thanks, You mean we have to create an external blog website for this?

Comment: @ub_303: as answered by andy you have to add a custom link in the menu with `press.example.com` and in the lable you can write "Blog".

Comment: @ Raunak Gupta  so it means we have to make an external blog with press.example.com ?

Comment: You can either create a separate install or a multisite which is a bit more complex... the simple rule is one website is one install and should have 1 URL other URLS will/should redirect to the main URL so to have 2 separate "Main URls" the best practice would be to have 2 sites or a multi site